# Symfony 2 add relationship on existing entities (courses & courses_students & students)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to symfony framework. I would like to ask you guys how to add relationship on existing entities. I have `students`, `courses` and `courses_students` tables. In students table there are 3 students and in courses table there are 2 courses. In below code I am using findAll() function. But in my development I am passing array from twig template.

1. How can I add records in courses_students table using ajax?
2. How can I remove records in courses_students table using ajax?

   ```
   public function amcsAction(Request $request){
       if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
           $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $course = $em->getRepository('FicusEschoolBundle:Course')->find($request->get('cid'));

           if (!$course) {
               throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Course entity.');
           }

           $students = $em->getRepository('FicusEschoolBundle:Student')->findAll();

           $course->addStudent($students);
           $em->persist($course);
           $em->flush();

       }
   }
   ```

**UPDATED**: Info about Entity

Course Table

```
 private $teacher;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Subject", inversedBy="courses")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subject_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $subject;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Coursetype", inversedBy="courses")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="coursetype_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $coursetype;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Schoolclass", inversedBy="courses")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="schoolclass_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $schoolclass;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Student", mappedBy="courses")
 */
private $students;
```

Student Table

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="enrolledDate", type="datetime")
 */
private $enrolledDate;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Course")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="courses_students", 
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="student_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $courses;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Studentprofile", mappedBy="student")
 */
private $studentProfile;
```

Jquery Function

```
    function mcs() {
        sids = [];
        $('#selectedStudents option').each(function (i, selected) {
            sids.push($(selected).val());
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('amcs') }}",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            data: {"cid": _cid, "students": sids}
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please give some information about your entities. Do you use ManyToMany?

Comment: What sort of error are you getting?  Not seeing what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

1. You missed to list "courses_students" entity, but I suppose it looks like:

   ```
   class CoursesStudent{

     /**
      * @var integer
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      */
      private $id;

      /**
       * @var \path\Entity\Student
       *
       * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\path\Student\Entity\User", inversedBy="courses")
       * @ORM\JoinColumns({
       *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="student_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
       * })
       */
       private $student;

       /**
        * @var \path\Entity\Course
        *
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\path\Entity\Course", inversedBy="courses")
        * @ORM\JoinColumns({
        *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="category_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
        * })
        */
        private $course;
   }
   ```

And in your controller:

```
public function amcsAction(Request $request){
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $course = $em->getRepository('FicusEschoolBundle:Course')->find($request->get('cid'));

        if (!$course) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Course entity.');
        }

        $student = $em->getRepository('FicusEschoolBundle:Student')->find($request->get('student_id'));

        $object = new CoursesStudent();
        $object->setStudent($student);
        $object->setCourse($course);
        $em->persist($object);
        $em->flush();

    }
}
```

2. If you want to remove a record from "courses_students", you need the ID, or the student & course ids and identify the courses_students.ID based by that.

Comment: So you mean that I have to create CoursesStudents class in my Entity folder right? Because according to the default entity generator there was no such class created.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You need such a table if your student can attend more courses.

Comment: I already have that table in database. Because on my Course and Student class there are ManyToMany relation. As result of ManyToMany relation table has been already created. But in my symfony project there are just 2 Entity class one for Student and the other one for Course class. There is no CoursesStudent class was created using entity generator.

Comment: You won't see a table for that if your many-to-many relation doesn't have any fields besides the two foreign keys.